# How to read child elements from a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I want to get a list of all child elements of a react component.

For example:

**Parent.js**

```
<Parent>
   <SomeComponent/>
</Parent>
```

**SomeComponent.js**

```
<SomeComponent>
   <ChildElement1/>
   <ClhidElement2/>
</SomeComponent>
```

So in `Parent.js` I want to get `ChildElement1` and `ChildElement2`.
Is that possible?

My Use case is:

I'm passing form fields (Field component) to a generic Form component. The Form element receives an object of default values and also other things (what CRUD/resource it is related to for example). And it must inject these values in the Fields. Instead of passing all fields one by one and avoid repetion I created containers like "UserFields" and a few others and they are the ones that have the Fields components. So I need Form to read the Fields in UserFields. But since the fields are already inside UserFields, I can't figure out how to get them.

Comment: May I ask what your use case it?

Comment: Sure. I just updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I am considering that your child components are mapped from array inside `<SomeComponent />`

Try this inside your parent

```
state = {
   child: []
}
renderChildren = () => {
   if(this.state.child.length > 0) {
      return this.state.child.map(e => {
          return (
             <div>{e}</div>
          )
      })
   }
}
returnChild = (data) => {
   var child = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      child.push(data[i])
   }
   this.setState(prevState => ({child: [...prevState.child, child]}));
}
return (
    <div>
       <SomeComponent returnChild={(child) => this.returnChild(child)} />
       {this.renderChildren()}
    </div>
)
```

Add this method to your `<SomeComponent />` component like this along with other code.

```
onGettingMoreChild = (child) => {
    this.props.returnChild(child)
}
```

Don't forget to call `onGettingMoreChild` whenever there is a new child created.

I have not tested this code. Please playaround with it if needed. Also, remember to pass in your entire view as `child` to the method `onGettingMoreChild`

Example of `child` variable passed to `onGettingMoreChild` is

```
<div>I am child one!!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`React` is designed to be unidirectional data flow and following `Flux` architecture, and hence to keep best practices, it's always top down (from parent to child, not bidirectional).

However, you can achieve them in several options such as implementing [React with redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) or [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)